# Derivative of $f(x) = x^5$ using the definition.

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x^5,$ and $\quad P(1,1)$ $(a = 1,\text{ and } f(a) = 1)$.

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}h \implies\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(1+h)^5 - 1}h=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}h((1+h)^5-1)$$

After This I'm lost. I don't know how to handle $x^5$.

I know it's simple, but I can't find anything to help me.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you seen Pascal's triangle or the binomial theorem? They tell you how to expand quantities like $(a+b)^n$ quickly

Comment: No I have not. I'll look those up.

Comment: expand $(1+h)^5$ there will be only one term surviving in numerator after you subtract 1 and take limit. Check that it is?

Comment: I think this is a pointless exercise. You can just prove the product rule and use that to show that $\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$ by induction.

Comment: You don't need binomials for that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Take $l = h + 1$ then $l \to 1$ as $h \to 0$ and

$$\lim_{l\to 1} \frac{l^5 - 1}{l -1}$$

Use $l^5 - 1 = (l-1)(l^4 + l^3 +l^2 +l + 1)$.

Can you get it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the double-headed arrow you want an equals sign. Anyway, expand (1+h)^5 using one of these methods:
1. binomial theorem
2. Pascal's triangle in conjunction with the binomial theorem
3. Simply multiply all the factors of (1+h)(1+h)(1+h)(1+h)(1+h) together.
Or use a theorem to get the answer:
4. By the "power rule" for derivatives, the limit should be 5a^4 when a=1.

Comment: I'm aware of the power's rule. I'm re-covering calculus I already know to work on my bad algebra. Using the power rule is kinda cheating in this respect.

Comment: @Leonard Here is a [Mathjax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

From the binomial theorem,

$$(1 + h)^5 = \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} h^i = 1 + 5h + h^2\sum_{i=2}^5 \binom{5}{i} h^{i-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Binomial theorem: $(x+y)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} x^i y^{n-i}$. Thus $$(h+1)^5 =\\ \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} h^i =\\ \binom{5}{5}h^5 + \binom{5}{4}h^4 + \binom{5}{3}h^3 + \binom{5}{2}h^2 + \binom{5}{1}h + \binom{5}{0} =\\ h^5 + 5h^4 + 10h^3 + 10h^2 + 5h + 1$$

You can also calculate $(1+h)^5$ directly just by using $n^{a+b} = n^a n^b$ and $c(a+b) = ca + cb$ repeatedly. For example you probably know that $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$. So then $(x+1)^5 = (x+1)^2 (x+1)^3 = (x^2 + 2x + 1)(x+1)^3 = x^2 (x + 1)^3 + 2x(x+1)^3 + (x+1)^3$, etc.